# Implementing activeX control to view PowerPoint slides in Windows forms using c#, not showing control

Tags: c#, .net, forms, activex, powerpoint

I'm working on a project and I need to embed a PowerPoint viewer in windows forms. I'm using the following activeX control: http://www.daolnwod.com/free-powerpoint-viewer-activex.html.

I activated the control to be used with the form designer's toolbox and dragged it into my form. I then edited the code in the InitializeComponent() method to the following:

```
this.axPowerPointViewer1 = new AxPOWERPOINTVIEWERLib.AxPowerPointViewer();

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axPowerPointViewer1)).BeginInit();
this.axPowerPointViewer1.Enabled = true;
this.axPowerPointViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.axPowerPointViewer1.Name = "axPowerPointViewer1";
this.axPowerPointViewer1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axPowerPointViewer1.OcxState")));
this.axPowerPointViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(925, 573);
this.axPowerPointViewer1.TabIndex = 5;
//this.axPowerPointViewer1.CreateControl();
this.Controls.Add(this.axPowerPointViewer1);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axPowerPointViewer1)).EndInit();
```

And in my Forms constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    axPowerPointViewer1.Show();
    bool loaded = axPowerPointViewer1.LoadFile(@"C:\Debug\test2.ppt"); // loaded = false

    string z = axPowerPointViewer1.GetSlideCount().ToString();
}
```

However, when I'm opening the form nothing shows up. The code compiles but I can't see my test slide that I've been working on. I have created 2 buttons for 'Previous' and 'Next' slides but debugging gives me a slide location of 0 every time so something must be wrong and I can't seem to find it.

---

**UPDATE**

The problem has been solved. It seems I didn't call axPowerPointviewer1.InitControl(). It still has a few troubles, sometimes it won't display the first slide at startup. If things keep running smoothly I'll post an answer to this problem.

Comment: Maybe move the code from your constructor/InitializeComponent method into your Form_Load event? You may be running this code before your form has loaded?

Comment: Problem has been solved. It seemed I was missing an Initcontrol() call and after calilng that method the activeX element was working properly, although sometimes it has trouble showing the first slide.

Comment: Cool, if you figure out the answer to a question you yourself have asked you can answer it below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in initialising the control. In order for the control to fully function you need to call the InitControl() method so call calling the following code should make the program work:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.axPowerPointViewer1.InitControl();
    }
```